# How can I change the order of the execution of automated tests when a build is run in TFS?

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, tfsbuild, build-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a build which executes the Coded UI tests on TFS. When I run the build, I've noticed that the tests are executed in the alphabetical order of the name of the test methods.

I tried setting the order in MTM but later came across [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vstsqualitytools/2009/11/20/order-test-cases/) which states:

> Please note this only applies to the manual tests but not automated
>   tests. For automated tests, the order you set here will not be
>   respected during test execution

Is there any way that I could specify the order in which the tests are to be executed?

Answer (score 1):

To run tests in order in Vnext build , you could add an **Ordered Test file** in your test project and run it in Vnext Build.

In the Test Drop location put the complete Project, and in the **Executions options** put the ordered test.

[image]

Comment: Hi @patrick-MSFT where could I find the above screen? I created an ordered test but I couldn't figure out to how to execute it during the a scheduled build.

Comment: You just need to add a *Run Functional Test* step in your build definition. Details please refer this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/03/31/executing-automated-tests-in-build-vnext-using-test-plan-test-suites/

Comment: The builds I use were created from Visual Studio (I think this is a XAML build?), not VS Team Services. I don't seem to have permission to create a build using Build vNext so I guess I'll have to work on that first.

Comment: Seems you are using XAML build, you can still use ordered test https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx. Just the same as using normal test assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ordered Tests which are explained here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182631.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I had difficulty getting it to execute as part of the automated build.

Comment: Please explain which problems you have to run these ordered tests.